# ошибка File "/Users/user/.atom/Atom", line 1 SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file /Users/user/.atom/Atom on line 1,

Tags: python, mac, atom

Когда я пытаюсь запустить этот код:

```py
name = 'Джеси'
age = 21
print('Привет, {}!n\Тебе уже {} год!'.format(name, age))
```

выходит ошибка:

```
File "/Users/user/.atom/Atom", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file /Users/user/.atom/Atom on line 1, but no  encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Kак исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10589620/13970074

Comment: Нужно пересохранить файл в кодировке UTF-8 или указать фактическую кодировку в начале файла, как описано в [PEP-263](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). У вас скорее всего сейчас файл в кодировке cp1251.

Comment: Возможно также запускаете с помощью Python2 вместо Python3